# Finding the limit: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x+y+2)e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Finding the limit: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x+y+2)e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)} $

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, I've tried evaluating directly via substitution (doesn't work obviously), I tried evaluating an x path and y path (x=0 and y=0) which also did not seem to work, I tried a quick polar substitution (x=rcostheta y=rsintheta) which once again did not seem to work.

Any thoughts on how to to evaluate? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$|x+y+2|{\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} \leq 2(x^2+y^2+1){\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}} 
 = 2(r^2+1){\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}$$
with the usual variable changes: $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $r>0$.

As $(x,y)\to 0$ implies $r\to 0$, and
$$ \lim_{r\to 0}2(r^2+1){\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{r^2}} =0, $$ 
the limit of our function is $0$.

Comment: I may be overlooking the obvious, but evaluating as r --> 0 will give me e^(-1/0): is this not undefined? How can I establish that the limit is 0?

Comment: -1/r^2 goes to minus infinity when r goes to 0 :)

Comment: $\frac{1}{r}\to +\infty $ as $r\to{+0},$ so that $-\frac{1}{r^2}\to -\infty$ and $e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}} \to {0} .$

Comment: Ah ha! I was looking at it differently, thank you for elaborating :) Got to learn something new too in the process, thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the polar substitution $$x=\rho\cos{\theta}, \\ y=\rho\sin{\theta}, $$ 
we have $$\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)} = \dfrac{1}{\rho^2}.$$
Then by the triangle inequality 
$$|x+y+2| \leqslant |x|+|y|+2 \leqslant 2\rho+2,$$
therefore
$$ \left| \dfrac{(x+y+2)}{e^{\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)}}} \right| \leqslant \dfrac{2\rho+2}{e^{\frac{1}{\rho^2}}} \underset{\rho\to{+0}}\to {0}.$$

Comment: I have not yet encountered the triangle inequality, something I will have to learn! Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: [Triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)